# Greasemonkey script to modify automatically an URL with a specific id value

Tags: url, replace, greasemonkey

I would like to change the url from "http://example.com/products/description/product123/index.html" to "http://example.com/f123456/products/description/product123/index.html".
For every link from a specific site (just one) I need to change that like in the example, to add a code after the base of the link, after that to continue with the normal link.

And to be more specific, here is the link I would like to modify with my script: http://www.f64.ro/ to be http://www.f64.ro/f444618/ for every link, product, etc.

I tried something that I found but it doesn't work and I don't know what is wrong.

```
    // ==UserScript==
    // @name     F64.ro
    // @include  http://www.f64.ro/*
    // ==/UserScript==

    var targID      = "f444618/";
    var targLink    = document.querySelector ("#" + targID);
    targLink.href  += targID + "\/";
```

Thank you!

Comment: You do realise that that this affects your browser only? Nobody else will be affected by it.

Comment: Yes, I realise that but I just want to be able to copy the modified URL and paste it to someone or somewhere, if it is possible, instead modifing manual every link. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 7):

There are similar questions on stackoverflow, for example [How can you replace a link's target in Greasemonkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2678615/33499).

Based on that, here is an example which modifies all links on this site pointing to stackoverflow.com into www.stackoverflow.com.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           changeurl test
// @namespace      https://stackoverflow.com/
// @description    test for https://stackoverflow.com/q/10267423/33499
// @include        https://stackoverflow.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

var links,thisLink;
links = document.evaluate("//a[@href]",
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null);
for (var i=0;i<links.snapshotLength;i++) {
    var thisLink = links.snapshotItem(i);

    thisLink.href = thisLink.href.replace('https://stackoverflow.com/',
                                          'http://www.stackoverflow.com/');
}
```

Comment: [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript) is the way to go, although not too much thought seemed to go into its development...

Answer (score 4):

If it is a fixed number

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name           TESTE 2
// @namespace      TESTE 2
// @description    TESTE 2
// @include        http*://*stackoverflow*
// ==/UserScript==

for (var i=0,link; (link=document.links[i]); i++) {
    linkID = '/f444618'
    link.href = link.href.replace(location.hostname, location.hostname+linkID);
}
```

If the number changes from link to link, just get the ID for the current link and replace `linkID = 'f444618'`